# R: Does this graph make sense? (understanding graphs, applications for COVID-19)

Tags: r, graph, data-visualization, cluster-analysis, nodes

I am working with the R programming language. Suppose I have a dataset which describes the business relationships between a group of grocery stores and their customers. In this example:

1. Customers can shop at different Grocery Stores
2. "Grocery Stores" themselves can shop at other Grocery Stores (i.e.
   the owners of grocery stores frequently visit other grocery stores
   to buy products for their own stores)
3. Customers can buy and sell between themselves

The code to generate some sample data looks like this:

```
library(igraph)

my_data <- data.frame(

"node_a" = c("Store_A", "Store_A", "Store_A", "Store_B", "Store_B", "Store_C", "Store_C", "Store_C", "Store_C", "Store_C", "Store_B", "Store_C", "customer_4", "customer_9", "customer_1"),
"node_b" = c("customer_1", "customer_2", "customer_3", "customer_3", "customer_4", "customer_2", "customer_5", "customer_6", "customer_7", "Store_B", "customer_9","customer_9", "customer_5", "customer_4", "customer_1")
)
```

From here, I am not sure if the next steps are logical. In normal circumstances, the "nodes" in the graph would all be of the same "type" - e.g. all the nodes would be "customers". In my example, the nodes are either "customers" or "stores". In my view, on some level this is like "comparing apples to oranges" : even though the graph is describing business relationships between customers and stores, a store is significantly different, "bigger and stronger" than an individual customer. I am not sure if it makes sense to create a graph in which all the nodes are not homogenous.

Here is the graph that is created - I made the nodes corresponding to "stores" significantly larger to display the inherent difference between a "customer" vs a "store":

```
node_size <- data.frame(col = unique(unlist(my_data)))
node_size$size <- c("50","50","50","15","15","15","15","15","15","15","15")

graph <- graph.data.frame(my_data, directed=T)
graph <- simplify(graph)

plot(graph, vertex.size = as.numeric(node_size$size))
```

[image]

If this graph makes logical sense, I am then interested in performing clustering ("community detection") on this graph in order to find interesting sub-networks :

```
fc <- fastgreedy.community(graph)
plot( fc, graph, vertex.size = as.numeric(node_size$size))
```

[image]

If such a graph can be logically constructed, I hope clustering algorithms (e.g. fastgreedy, louvain, girvan-newman) can be performed on this graph and "highly connected" clusters can be identified which can be used to determine which stores/customers are at risk of getting COVID-19.

Can someone please tell me if this idea makes sense : can a graph be constructed where the nodes are not all of the same "type"? (e.g. a graph being composed of grocery stores and customers vs a graph just being composed of customers)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Not sure if this is the most relevant platform for this question since it seems more theoretical than an actual "code relevant" issue. That being said,
2. It does make sense to me.

IMHO, look at it this way. Let's say the nodes represent the "act of selling a good". This then gives a uniform definition across the "grocery stores" and "customers". The only underlying assumption would be that any "customer" acting as a "seller" and making a transaction would be restricted to a single location for all such transactions, say, their residence.

If we can align to the above thought, the only thing I'd change in your approach is to set the `node_size$size` in proportion to the business done by the node, i.e., `count` or `volume` of transactions through the node.